# If H is normal p-subgroup of G, then H is contained in every sylow-p subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Actually I proved this by using conjugation.

I would like to know that it is still true if H is not normal.

Also, there always exists sylow-p subgroup that contains p-subgroup of G?

Comment: If you proved that using conjugation, that's a pretty good sign that no, the result doesn't hold for $H$ that aren't normal. I also can't make heads or tails of your last statement. It's true, and one of the main Sylow theorems, is it not? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Is it a theorem? Then, I haven't yet covered that part.

Comment: The condition that $H$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is equivalent to $H$ being the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, so if $H$ is not normal then there is more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup, and the statement is obviously false.