# If H is normal p-subgroup of G, then H is a subset in every sylow-p subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

How to proof the statement

> If H is normal p-subgroup of G, then H is a subset in every sylow-p subgroup.

This question was asked before in

[If H is normal p-subgroup of G, then H is contained in every sylow-p subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200530/if-h-is-normal-p-subgroup-of-g-then-h-is-contained-in-every-sylow-p-subgroup)

and the author claims to have proved it but didn't present his proof. Does anyone know to proof this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By Sylow Theorems (=ST), all Sylow subgroups for a given prime are conjugate, and also by ST any $p$- subgroup is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup , so there exists

$$P\in Syl_p(G)\;,\;\;H\subset P\stackrel{\text{because}\;H\lhd G}\implies \;\forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;H^x=H\subset P^x$$

and since *any* element in $\;Syl_p(G)\;$ is of the form $\;P^x\;$ we've finished.